# Best approach for verifying a FutureCallback effect with Jmockit

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

What is the preferred mechanism for verifying the effects of a callback in Jmockit?

For example, assume I have this class.

```
class ResultGenerator {
    AsyncLauncher asyncLauncher = new AsyncLauncher();

    public void getResultAsync(final ResultSignal resultSignal) {
        asyncLauncher.getResult(new FutureCallback<Result>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@Nullable Result result) {
                    resultSignal.success(result);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    resultSignal.failure();
                }
        });
    }
}
```

How do I verify `resultSignal.success(result)` when writing a test for `ResultGenerator#getResultAsync`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class ResultGeneratorTest {
    // Synchronous invocation, mocked AsyncLauncher
    @Test
    public void testGetResultAsync(@Mocked final ResultSignal resultSignal, @Mocked final Result result) throws Exception {
        new MockUp<AsyncLauncher>() {
            @Mock
            void getResult(FutureCallback<Result> futureCallback) {
                futureCallback.onSuccess(result);
            }
        };
        ResultGenerator resultGenerator = new ResultGenerator();
        resultGenerator.getResultAsync(resultSignal);
        new Verifications() {{
            resultSignal.success((Result) any); times = 1;
            resultSignal.failure(); times = 0;
        }};
    }

    // Asynchronous invocation, real AsyncLauncher in use
    @Test
    public void testGetResultAsyncDelayed(@Mocked final Result result) throws Exception {
        final AtomicBoolean latch = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        MockUp<ResultSignal> resultSignalMockUp = new MockUp<ResultSignal>() {
            @Mock(invocations = 1)
            public void success(Result result) {
                latch.set(true);
            }

            @Mock(invocations = 0)
            public void failure() {
                latch.set(true);
            }
        };
        ResultGenerator resultGenerator = new ResultGenerator();
        final ResultSignal resultSignal = resultSignalMockUp.getMockInstance();
        resultGenerator.getResultAsync(resultSignal);
        Awaitility.await().untilTrue(latch);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of notes:

1. **`ResultGenerator` is your SUT (System Under Test)** and you should not mock internals
2. **`ResultSignal` is a test collaborator**, so it is natural to mock it out
3. because you can verify the functionality as such, the only "correct" solution from unit testing theory is to mock out the collaborator
4. **You have to be sure that you handle timeout correctly**, otherwise the test might never end

so one possible solution is:

```
@Test
public void getResultAsync_ShouldNotifyResultSignal() throws InterruptedException {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    ResultGenerator generator = new ResultGenerator();

    generator.getResultAsync(new MyResultSignal(latch));

    assertTrue(latch.await(1, SECONDS));
}

private static final class MyResultSignal implements ResultSignal {
    private final CountDownLatch latch;

    private MyResultSignal(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void success(Result result) {
        latch.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void failure() {}
}
```